# CP-SAT optimization

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

99% of the time my problems of optimization have ONLY a huge number of boolean decision variables(400K) and linear constraints. I'm wondering if I can increase the performance of CP-SAT avoiding unnecessary solver actions using some of the parameters listed here:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/sat_parameters.proto

I'm using python

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
linearization_level:0
```

or

```
num_search_workers:8
```

Comment: are they alternatives or can I use both?

Comment: num_search_workers:8 will include one worker with linearization_level:0